# Is it possible to complete remove keyword template in C++ 20 for concepts?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, c++-concepts

For example using Visual Studio 16.3 with the

/std:c++latest

flag as declared here [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-concepts-are-here-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/) I can write.

```
#include <concepts>

template <std::integral T>
T plus1(T a) {
    return a + 1;
}


int main() {

    auto i = plus1(10);

}
```

However I can't write

```
#include <concepts>

std::integral plus1(std::integral a) {
    return a + 1;
}


int main() {

    auto i = plus1(10);

}
```

But I read [here](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t13-prefer-the-shorthand-notation-for-simple-single-type-argument-concepts) that this should be possible.

Comment: The correct syntax is `std::integral auto a`. I don't know if MSVC supports that yet (and the latest version on godbolt doesn't seem to support either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Concepts TS offered what is called "terse syntax", which allows you to implicitly declare a function to be a template by using a concept instead of a typename in a parameter list. This was deemed controversial by the ISO C++ committee when attempting to incorporate Concepts TS into the standard. They wanted a way to know by looking at a function declaration whether it was a template or not.

After some back and forth, they [came up with an alternate terse syntax](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html): you use `auto` deduction (taken from generic lambdas), constrained by a concept name:

```
std::integral auto plus1(std::integral auto a) {
    return a + 1;
}
```

However, most concepts implementations at present implement the Concepts TS functionality, with the newer stuff not yet implemented. VS never had a Concepts TS implementation, and they explicitly say that they have not yet implemented terse template syntax of this sort.

Comment: IMHOt C++ doesn't make much sense without templates, and it was only the syntax and lack of concepts that were preventing such generalization earlier (and compiler tech, too). Personally, C++ looks to me now - finally - like the language it was supposed to have been from the beginning; I have looked critically at a bunch of my old code and turning all functions into generic ones would have had no negative impact whatsoever, as long as there was a way to express concepts. `template` was a crutch. The patient's convalescence is done. This crutch, and the cast on the arm, and bandage, should go.

Comment: None of the foregoing is meant to bash the messenger of course. At least `auto` is terser indeed. I would of course believe if someone with a big codebase said "look,we've ran automatic refactoring and made everything generic and it turned the product for worse on both the engineering and the user ends". Barring such concrete engineering reasons, I am all but baffled by the insistence on knowing whether the type has a constant value, or is given by a predicate (the concept). `x^2=16` expresses `x in {-4, 4}`, and so do concepts, so it's not as if the types become unpredictable...

Comment: @KubaOber: "*I have looked critically at a bunch of my old code and turning all functions into generic ones would have had no negative impact whatsoever, as long as there was a way to express concepts.*" Then I guess you don't have to do a lot of DLL interfacing or passing function pointers around or writing virtual functions, any of which make a template interface impossible. That's not to denigrate your code or anything, but C++ is bigger than you are. That's probably the most important thing the ISO committee has to (and does) remember: C++ is bigger than any one programmer.

Comment: I would think that it's clear that APIs that are meant to hide the code would need to expose only concrete types, but whatever APIs are OK to be exposed (perhaps with obfuscated internals) just go into the header... Template functions/methods get instantiated the moment you create a function pointer, since the function pointer needs a concrete type, so the compiler does exactly what is expected. I consider the "DLL interfacing" and "passing function pointers around" to be a ruse that can be deobfuscated by trying to do it. It works, and it's not complicated.

Comment: @KubaOber: We wrote a [paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1392r0.html) about all the reasons you need to know that a “generic function” is not a (single) function at all.

Answer (score -2):

No. Only in basic cases.
In some situations you may need, for example, an exact type. 
For instance, to do a forwarding call you write

```
template <class ... TT>
void SomeFunc(TT && ... tt)
 {
  AnotherFunc( std::forward<TT>(tt)... );
 }
```

Comment: This could be written as `void SomeFunc(auto&&... tt) { AnotherFunc(std::forward<decltype(tt)>(tt)...); }`. That's not to say it's nicer to read, but referring to the title, it is possible to remove the `template` keyword.

Comment: There are other situations, where you have to use template. This one is just an example. So, the right answe is NO.